# Facebook Login + Drupal 8 custom module. POST variable not being allowed/detected in db_select

Tags: ajax, facebook, drupal, facebook-login, drupal-8

I have created a custom module in Drupal 8 that allows a user to authenticate using facebook login. Their access token is checked against one stored in the database and if it matches authenticates the user and if it doesn't then redirects them to a page that allows them to link their Facebook account to a Drupal user.

The button for login is:

```
<button id="login_fb" onclick="logIt()">Log in with Facebook</button>
```

The "logit" function with the ajax request to the Drupal controller is:

```
function logIt()
{
 FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
    if(response.authResponse.accessToken)
    {
          var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/user/token",
            method: "POST",
            data: { access_token : response.authResponse.accessToken},
            dataType: "json"
          });

          request.done(function( msg ) {
            window.location.replace(msg['redirect_url']);
          });

          request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
          });
    }
    }
}
```

And the controller code that handles this ajax call is:

```
public function token() {


    $fb_token = $_POST['access_token'];

    $query = db_select('user__field_fb_token', 'u');
    $query
      ->fields('u')
      ->condition('u.field_fb_token_value', $fb_token,'=');

    $res = $query->execute();
    $res->allowRowCount = TRUE;
    $count = $res->rowCount();


//See if anybody has this access token
if($count > 0)
{
    $user = $res->fetchAssoc();
    //TODO: Refresh access token and update

    $login_id = $user['entity_id'];
    //Redirect the user to topics
    user_login_finalize(user_load($login_id));

    $response_arr = array("status" => "authorised","redirect_url" => "/topics");

}
else
{

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $fb_token;
    $response_arr = array("status" => "unauthorised","redirect_url" => "/user/auth","token" => $fb_token);

}



$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(json_encode($response_arr));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;

}
```

The weird thing is that the db_select query always returns 0 and therefore does not authenticate the user account that has this token. However replacing

```
 $fb_token = $_POST['access_token'];
```

with

```
 $fb_token = '** hard coded access token **';
```

yields the correct result. I have checked that the post variable being passed in and it is present (that's why I pass it back with the unauthorised response to check that it's not blank).

I think it may have something to do with the async nature of FB.Login method but not sure.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Access tokens have an expiry time, they are not valid forever. Therefor it makes little sense to use them as the criterion to identify the user. You should use the app-scoped user id for that purpose.

Comment: The code reissues and updates access tokens periodically. It's a project that cannot store any identifiable information so the user id was off limits unfortunately.

Comment: An authentication system that is not allowed to store any “identifiable” information? Makes little sense IMHO. Plus, the user access token makes the user “identifiable” as well, so that whole argument collapses on itself.

Comment: It's part of a University study so we need to be able to track individual data - but not identify who that data belongs to. The access token itself does not provide a link to a user outside of the Facebook App and invalidates previous tokens once a token has been refreshed.

Comment: Furthermore access tokens will be encrypted in the DB the same as passwords to allow a secondary level of security.

Comment: Storing passwords _encrypted_ (as opposed to _hashed_) would also be rather a security fail. But if an encrypted or hashed token would satisfy your requirements, then an encrypted or hashed user id should do so in the same way.